# Integral of L^1 function outside a large ball

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R).$ Let $r$ be any real number and let $B_r:=\{x:|x|\le r\}.$

Then we know, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus B_r} |f(x)|dx\to0\,\text{ as }\,r \to \infty.$$

My question is, how to prove this by definition (i.e. without appealing to any theorem or fancy stuff)?

**My method (involving dominated convergence theorem):**

$\int_{\mathbb R}|f\chi_{B_r}|\le\int_{\mathbb R}|f|\lt \infty$ and $f\chi_{B_r}\to f$ pointwisely as $r\to\infty$, where $\chi_{B_r}$ is the characteristic function on $B_r.$ Then by the dominated convergence theorem, we are done.

Comment: You have $r\to 0$?

Comment: @zhw. It was a typo. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is an integrable  simple function, say $\sum a_iI{E_i}$ ( where $E_i$'s are pairwise disjoint measurable sets) then the result follow from the fact that $\mu (E_i \setminus B_r) \to 0$. [Note that $\mu (E_i) <\infty$]. The general case follows from the fact that there exists a simple function $g$ with $\int |f-g| d\mu <\epsilon$. 
Note that $\int_{\mathbb R \setminus B_r} |f-g|d\mu <\epsilon$ for all $r$.

Comment: Thanks. But in the definition of simple functions, $\mu (E_i)$ may be $\infty$ right? However, for the simple function $g$ which approximates $f$, $\mu (E_i) <\infty$.

Comment: @SamWong I meant integrable simple function.

Comment: Then it is clearly correct. Thanks!